# Suggestions about managing hardware-dependent configurations in C using separate files?

Tags: c, build, configuration, embedded

I'm currently working on an embedded systems project that utilizes the same C99 code base across three hardware models. The primary differences between these models are encapsulated in constant arrays that store sensor mappings. Below is a simplified example illustrating the configuration for each hardware model:

```c
// Configuration example
#if defined(MODEL_A)
    // Configuration for Model A
    #define PRODUCT_CODE 1
    #define NUMBER_OF_SENSORS 5
    const int temperature_sensor_map[NUMBER_OF_SENSORS] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
#elif defined(MODEL_B)
    // Configuration for Model B
    #define PRODUCT_CODE 2
    #define NUMBER_OF_SENSORS 3
    const int temperature_sensor_map[NUMBER_OF_SENSORS] = { 0, 2, 4 };
#define NUMBER_OF_SENSORS 3
#elif defined(MODEL_C)
    // Configuration for Model C
    // ...
#else
    #error Define MODEL_A, MODEL_B, or MODEL_C
#endif
```

To improve the management of these configurations and facilitate tracking changes in Git, I'm considering breaking the configuration into multiple files, each tailored to a specific hardware model. However, this approach would involve creating seven files, which seems overly complex:

```
- config.h (Main configuration header)
- config_model_a.h and config_model_a.c (Configuration for Model A)
- config_model_b.h and config_model_b.c (Configuration for Model B)
- config_model_c.h and config_model_c.c (Configuration for Model C)
```

Below is an example of the code.

Note: the use of global variables, as shown below, is not a concern, because the custom debugger used in this project has certain limitations, being able to inspect global variables only.

```c
// File config.h
#ifndef CONFIG_H
#define CONFIG_H

#if defined(MODEL_A)
    #include "config_model_a.h"
#elif defined(MODEL_B)
    #include "config_model_b.h"
#elif defined(MODEL_C)
    #include "config_model_c.h"
#else
    #error Define MODEL_A, MODEL_B, or MODEL_C
#endif

extern const int temperature_sensor_map[];

#endif // End of include guard
```

```c
// File config_model_a.h

#define PRODUCT_CODE 1
#define NUMBER_OF_SENSORS 5
```

```c
// File config_model_a.c

#if defined(MODEL_A)
    const int temperature_sensor_map[NUMBER_OF_SENSORS] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
#endif
```

```c
// File config_model_b.h

#define PRODUCT_CODE 2
#define NUMBER_OF_SENSORS 3
```

```c
// File config_model_b.c

#if defined(MODEL_B)
    const int temperature_sensor_map[NUMBER_OF_SENSORS] = { 0, 2, 4 };
#endif
```

Files for Model C follow a similar pattern

However, I'm exploring alternative approaches that don't rely on the build system and maintain clean, portable code. Specifically, I'm interested in solutions that eliminate the need for multiple include files or .c files.

Do you have suggestions that don't depend on the build system?

(I don't want to rely on the build system because we currently use Eclipse CDT but plan to transition to CMake in the future and I want the solution to work in both systems)

Comment: How does this depend on the build-system though? Any build-system allows you to define MODEL_A (or at least: I definitely know that cmake does)

Comment: *"However, this approach would involve creating seven files, which seems overly complex:"* It doesn't seem complex to me; it actually seems like a right choice.

Comment: *"facilitate tracking changes in Git"* It is a bit unclear to me what you mean by this, but I guess it doesn't mean using branching for different machines. Which is good. I used to have project with five machines in five repos, and copying code between branches became so time consuming, that I eventually merged everything into single branch and used similar system as you are suggesting.

Comment: But having single executable with runtime hardware detection is best if you can do it, like emiled suggested in their answer. When people in production need to only worry about one executable, it reduces chance for errors.

Comment: I agree with @user694733 that creating project-specific files is most often the way to go. You can then handle your products in separate projects, with separate builds and separate branches in version control. This also sates coding standards like MISRA C which forbid code that isn't used to be present.

Comment: The alternatives: `#ifdef` "compiler switch hell" quickly turns unreadable and error prone - everyone hates reading and maintaining such code. Polymorphism implementations are possible but tend to add a lot of complexity, which in turn leads to more bugs. A third alternative might be to store configurations in non-volatile memory such as eeprom/data flash, but that requires the various alternatives to be quite similar and you also need to have considered this in the design phase before you picked MCU.

Answer (score 3):

If you do not want to rely on the buid system, one solution is to do the configuration at runtime. **For this, your software needs to be able to recognize the hardware model (e.g. using a different voltage divider for each model).**

The idea is to create an *interface*, which is used by software components that need to read the sensors. You then create a pair of .h/.c config files, in which you provide functions to get the right sensor.

```
// sensor_config.h

// Enum with models
typedef enum {
    MODEL_A,
    MODEL_B,
    // ...
} model_t;

// Your interface
typedef struct {
    int (*get_product_code)(void);
    int (*get_number_of_sensors)(void);
    int (*get_sensor_map_at)(int);
} sensor_config_t ;

// Getter
sensor_config_t* get_sensor_config(model_t model);

// other models...
```

And the .c file

```
// sensor_config.c

// Model A

#define N_SENSORS_A 5

static int get_product_code_model_a(void);
static int get_number_of_sensors_model_a(void);
static int get_sensor_at_model_a(int sensor_id);

static sensor_config_t sensor_a 
{
    &get_product_code_model_a,
    &get_number_of_sensors_model_a,
    &get_sensor_at_model_a
};

static int get_product_code_model_a(void)
{
    return 1;
}

static int get_number_of_sensors_model_a(void)
{
    return N_SENSORS_A;
}

static int get_sensor_at_model_a(int sensor_id)
{
    static const int mapping[N_SENSORS_A] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
    
    // TODO: check index...

    return mapping[sensor_id];
}

// Model B

#define N_SENSORS_B 3

static int get_product_code_model_b(void);
static int get_number_of_sensors_model_b(void);
static int get_sensor_at_model_b(int sensor_id);

static sensor_t sensor_b 
{
    &get_product_code_model_b,
    &get_number_of_sensors_model_b,
    &get_sensor_at_model_b
};

static int get_product_code_model_b(void)
{
    return 2;
}

static int get_number_of_sensors_model_b(void)
{
    return N_SENSORS_B;
}

static int get_sensor_at_model_b(int sensor_id)
{
    static const int mapping[N_SENSORS_B] = {0, 2, 4};
    
    // TODO: check index...

    return mapping[sensor_id];
}

// other models...

// Getter    
sensor_config_t* get_sensor_config(model_t model)
{
    if (model == MODEL_A)
    {
         return &sensor_a;
    }
    else if (model == MODEL_B)
    {
        return &sensor_b;
    }
    else 
    { 
        // More models...
    } 
    return NULL;
}
```

Before your sensors get configured/read out, the software reads the hardware model and gets the right sensor.

```
// main.c

#include "sensor_config.h"

// Your sensor object
sensor_config_t* my_sensor_config = NULL;

void main(void){
 
    // Assign the right sensor config depending on the model
    model_t hw_model = read_hw_model(); // Read voltage from divider and deduct model    
    my_sensor_config = get_sensor_config(hw_model);
    // TODO : check that my_sensor_config is not NULL...    
        
    while(1)
    {
         // Do something with the sensor config
         int product_code = my_sensor_config->get_product_code();
         int n_sensors  = my_sensor_config->get_number_of_sensors();
         int first_sensor = my_sensor_config->get_sensor_at(0);
         int second_sensor = my_sensor_config->get_sensor_at(1);
         // ...
     }
}
```

Note : This adds a lot of overhead and potential errors. If you are limited in terms of memory and computing power, you might want to stick with a solution using the build system. The downside is that you would have as many binaries as models, whereas you only have one binary with the solution with runtime configuration. There is no silver bullet, you will need to make trade-offs.

Comment: I would prefer OPs original solution, because this one prevents linters from discovering out-of-bounds-issues. But still +1 for this alternative technique.

Comment: Agree, this additional level of indirection makes it more difficult for linters. Debugging also can be more tedious. But on the other hand, your code using the sensor configuration is easier to test, because you can mock the configuration . Simply assign a test configuration to `my_sensor_config` :)

Comment: Going for single software with runtime configuration is definitely a best option. Having only one executable to deal with simplifies everything greatly.